# Organizar DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter, dataset

Tengo un data set con la siguiente estructura de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El cual lo estoy trabajando en un Jupyter notebook con Python

Y necesito reorganizar esta información, para que quede así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien me pudiera dar alguna opinión, se lo agradecería

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Nótese que esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a [edit](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Para organizar un dataFrame de pandas utlizamos un metodo llamado `sort_values()`

```
dataFrame.sort_values(by=['Fecha', 'Dia', 'Mes'], ascending=[True, False, False])
```

Pero si quieres organizar un dataFrame de R utilizamos el metodo

```
dataFrame %>% arrange(desc(Fecha), Dia, desc(Mes))
```

Un saludo :)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta!! Pero debo re organizar el dataframe, ya que en la primera imagen se ve que tengo una columna y las demás columnas son fechas, y a partir de ese data set es que debo desmenuzar la fecha, lo cual ya he realizado, añadiendo una columna Fecha y separando con el método pd.to_datetime, mi mayor problema es como repetir una fecha, en este caso para A, B, C y D, tal como se ve en la 2° imagen del data Set.  Por último, estoy trabajndo los datos en Python, no soy muy avanzado en R. Saludos!!

Answer (score 0):

```
# Importando librerias
import pandas as pd
import datetime



# Creando Dataframe
d = ({'Col1': ["A", "B", "C", "D"], 
      '01/01/2020': [1, 9, 4, 7], 
      '02/01/2020': [2, 8, 5, 6],
      '03/01/2020': [3, 7, 6, 5],  
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


# Sacando la lista de las columnas
lista_fechas = list(df.columns)
lista_fechas.remove('Col1')

# Transponiendo el dataframe
df2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Col1'], value_vars=lista_fechas)

# Renombrando columna "variable"
df2 = df2.rename(columns={"variable": "Fecha"})


# Convirtiendo la columna Fecha en formato datetime
df2["Fecha"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["Fecha"])

# Extrayendo Dia, Mes, Año, Semana
df2["Dia"] = df2["Fecha"].dt.day
df2["Mes"] = df2["Fecha"].dt.month
df2["Año"] = df2["Fecha"].dt.year
df2["Semana"] = df2["Fecha"].dt.week

df2 = df2[["Col1", "Fecha", "Dia", "Mes", "Año", "value", "Semana"]]
```